# Angular is skipping array iteration but performing other tasks in the same scope

Tags: angular, typescript

**TLDR**: I am trying to loop over an array of data. I console log that data and see it exactly as I am expecting. I am able to use the data in my html template perfectly fine without issue, but if I try to log the length of the array or loop over the data in my TS file, it does not work. See attached screenshot and the saveOrigin function for the logs.

First code provided for context. The **saveOrigin** function further down the page is the location of the issue.

**Detailed explanation:** I am having issues looping over an array in angular 10 (I'm working with an older codebase and haven't updated because I don't want to break anything).

I am pushing data into an array, and then opening up a Material dialog and injecting that data. Almost everything works absolutely perfectly. I am able to loop over every piece of data in the HTML template and display it with no issues. I am able to console.log the data in the same scope as my loop and see it perfectly, but the loop doesn't work. I am going to try and attach enough code to give you an idea of what is going on.

here is where I push data into the dataloop (there can be up to 5 of these)

```
this.api.getTrucker(this.routeData[oVal], this.routeData[destVal], key).subscribe((dataTrucker: any[]) => {
        
            this.api.getAgent(this.routeData[destVal], key).subscribe((dataAgent: any[]) => {
              
              this.api.getDrop(this.routeData[oVal], key).subscribe((dataDrop: any[]) => {
                
                let dataLoop: JSONreturn = {
                  numberOf: i,
                  name: "Segment " + i,
                  destination: this.routeData[destVal],
                  destinationName: destVal,
                  origin: this.routeData[oVal],
                  originName: oVal,
                  drop: this.routeData[dropVal],
                  dropList: dataDrop,
                  dropName: dropVal,
                  truckerList: dataTrucker,
                  trucker: this.routeData[truckerVal],
                  truckerName: truckerVal,
                  agent: this.routeData[agentVal],
                  agentList: dataAgent,
                  agentName: agentVal,
                  comment: this.routeData[commentsVal],
                  commentName: commentsVal
                }
                this.routeSegment.push(dataLoop);
                this.saleAgent = this.routeData.SalesAgent;
                this.routeSegment.sort((a, b) => a.numberOf - b.numberOf);
              });
            });
          });
```

here is where I open the dialog with the data. Again, this all works perfectly. I just don't know if you need the context

```
const newDialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewRouteDialogComponent> = this.dialog.open(NewRouteDialogComponent, {
            width: 'auto',
            minWidth: '85vw',
            minHeight: '60vh',
            height: 'auto',
            data: {
              origin: this.origin,
              dest: this.dest,
              routeSegmentSort: this.routeSegment,
              truckUnid: this.truckUnid,
              direction: this.direction,
              routeData: this.routeData,
              saleAgent: this.saleAgent,
              min: this.min,
              max: this.max,
              airList: this.airList,
              airListAll: this.airListAll,
              salesList: this.salesList,
              chosenAir: this.chosenAir,
              newOrEdit: false
            }
          });

          newDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((res: any) => {
            console.log('route changes:', res);
            this.search('')
          })
```

I inject the data into the dialog like so... this also works perfectly and I am able to loop over ALL of this data in the html template without an issue

```
export interface DialogData {
  origin: string,
  dest: string,
  routeSegmentSort: Array<JSONreturn>,
  truckUnid: string,
  direction: string,
  routeData: any,
  min: boolean,
  max: boolean,
  saleAgent: any,
  airList: any[],
  salesList: any[],
  airListAll: any[],
  chosenAir: Array<string>,
  newOrEdit: boolean
}

constructor(
    private api: ApiService, 
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData, 
    public dialog: MatDialog, 
    private toastrService: NbToastrService,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewRouteDialogComponent>
    ) { 
      
    }
```

then I call this saveOrigin method in ngOnInit. Everything works absolutely fine except the else statement... the code inside the else brackets is running correctly because the console logs at the beginning and end are showing up, but it just skips the loop.

```
saveOrigin () {
    const sData = {
      "dbname": "data",
      "unid": this.data.truckUnid,
      "fieldname": 'Origin_1',
      "val": this.data.origin,
      "datatype": 'string'
    }
    if (this.data.newOrEdit) {
      this.api.fieldUpdate(sData).subscribe((data: any[]) => {
        console.log('fieldUpdate post response:',data);
        if (data['result'] == "success") {
          this.showToastUpdated('success', 'Created New Routing!');
        } else {
          this.showToastError('warning', 'ERROR! NOT Updated! TRY AGAIN!');
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log('route segment sort:', this.data.routeSegmentSort);
      try {
        console.log('route segment sort try:', this.data.routeSegmentSort);
        console.log('length:', this.data.routeSegmentSort.length)
        this.models = this.data.routeSegmentSort.map( (n: JSONreturn): string => (n.destination));
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
      console.log('models data:', this.models)
    }
  }
```

I have tried using map, forEach, for of, and even traditonal for loops. Same result.

I even created an array (random) of numbers the same length of routeSegmentSort and tried to map over that array like this

```
random: Array<number> = Array.from({length: this.data.routeSegmentSort.length}, (n, i) => i);

this.models = this.random.map((n: number) => this.data.routeSegmentSort[n].direction);
```

That didn't work either. The problem is that if I console log this.data.routeSegmentSort I get an array of objects back just as I am expecting and it will tell me the length. BUT if I console log the length with the SAME scope, I get zero.

here is a screenshot of the logs from the saveOrigin else statement

[browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNi5F.png)

I have no clue what is going on

Comment: There is a delay before the array is populated. What you're seeing is the result of lazy-loading in the debugger. Notice how the array appears empty until you click the drop-down arrow. The debugger does not load the array's contents until you click that arrow, at which point the array has been populated.

Comment: Considering OP stated they tried creating a random array, that's probably not the issue. When boiled down to the based code, OP's solution does work.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j8fd9w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts.  You've done a good effort but the code is still a bit hazy. Where is this.data loaded?

Comment: I am planning on using ngModels to update content on the page in real time. I need to first put the data in the models array, and then loop over it in the html template to display the initial data. Once displayed, it will let the users edit and see the changes in real time as they edit. But I need to populate the models array before I can add that functionality, and since it isn't working, I haven't done anything else yet